# What do you do if you don't want to put a keyword in your title?

Tags: seo, google, keywords, meta-tags, meta-keywords

Suppose you have a website about a subject, for instance, popcorn.

Everything in your site will be about popcorn and your regular visitors are popcorn enthusiasts who will understand that even articles without the keyword "popcorn" in the title are about popcorn.

How do you tell this to Google, if meta tags are not being used any more? Or do you have to keep adding "popcorn" to titles to have your articles show up in searches and news alerts? It's very awkward to keep adding a word to titles for this reason.

For instance, your title is `Why corn is good for you`, but it won't show up in Google searches, so do you really have to change it to "Why corn, from which popcorn is made, is good for you"?

I've noticed that adding the keyword to the website name, as in `Why corn is good for you | Popcorn Every Day` is not good enough.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Then don't put the keyword in your title.

Google are clever enough now to know what the page is about and how relevant it is for popcorn without you needing to include the word popcorn in the title.

Google can distinguish between similarities, synonyms and semantics. They'll be able to understand popcorn from corn. If you don't think the page is that relevant for popcorn, then use popcorn in the title.

All you need to do is worry about the user, make everything read well for the user and the search engines will find you for what you intend.

By the way, the page title isn't a meta tag and still remains as one of the important ranking factors used today.

If you're finding that you aren't being found for popcorn related queries in Google search, then maybe your content isn't as relevant for "popcorn" as you thought it was...

Comment: I'm actually thinking about Google Alerts. Whenever I add the keyword to my title, the story shows up in the alerts, but I tried to publish an article without it, and it was very relevant, because Google alerted me of every article that was published about that story, except my website's...

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. To receive Google Alerts, they have to be triggered by mentions of keywords, that's how Google Alerts work. If your content doesn't contain the keyword you've submitted to receive Google Alerts on, then you're not going to get an alert for that content.

Comment: The article contains the keyword, just not in the title, because the whole website is about that keyword. So does that mean I do have to put the keyword in the title?

Comment: No, to receive a Google Alert for mentions of keyword, the keyword just needs to be anywhere on the page, it doesn't have to be in the title. It's designed just to alert you when Google have indexed something new that contains what you wish to monitor. You can [see examples](https://support.google.com/alerts/answer/175928) from Google on this.

Comment: Well, I haven't had any luck with my articles showing up on alerts unless they contain the keyword in the title. But thanks for your insight.